# Is it possible to replace data-toggle="dropdown" for data-bs-toggle="dropdown" dynamically?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to change the data toggle attribute from `data-toggle="dropdown"` to `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` of some bootstrap elements dynamically as I can't access the code of these elements to make the change in another way.

Comment: @freedomn-m are you sure about the "caching" part? https://jsfiddle.net/qkwyb70h/1/ - appears to work fine, after you click the "toggle!" button - and BS is long done initializing at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').each(function() {
  this.setAttribute('data-bs-toggle', 'dropdown');
});
```

Something like this should do the trick.

It looks like BS5 is using event delegation to bind the functionality based on an attribute selector, so this should work independently of whether Bootstrap has already initialized at this point.